# sudo password asked when running yocto image for the first time (only)

Tags: yocto

I built `core-image-sato-dev` and after this when I did

`runqemu qemux86 core-image-sato-dev`

I got

```
runqemu - INFO - Running MACHINE=qemux86 bitbake -e...
runqemu - INFO - Continuing with the following parameters:

KERNEL: [/opt/yocto/thud_workspace/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/bzImage--4.18.33+git0+865683fc87_1a564c76f4-r0-qemux86-20220121081907.bin]
MACHINE: [qemux86]
FSTYPE: [ext4]
ROOTFS: [/opt/yocto/thud_workspace/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/core-image-sato-dev-qemux86.ext4]
CONFFILE: [/opt/yocto/thud_workspace/build/tmp/deploy/images/qemux86/core-image-sato-dev-qemux86.qemuboot.conf]

runqemu - INFO - Setting up tap interface under sudo
[sudo] password for yocto:
```

but only *the first time*

I don't know what password is this.
The second time I run this the password is not asked anymore

What is *setting up tap interface*??

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [sudo] password for yocto:
> ```
>
> I don't know what password is this. The second time I run this the password is not asked anymore

This message is from your OS, not from Yocto. The password is likely to be the login password for the `yocto` user in your OS.

Yocto is calling a `sudo` command, and so your OS prompts you to enter your sudo password. You only have to do this once, because your OS is probably remembering your sudo login for a short period of time.

---

> What is *setting up tap interface??*

A [TAP interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TUN/TAP) can be created within Linux's network stack, that acts like real network hardware on your PC, but each packet it receives can be sent to a userspace program (QEMU in this case) for processing. It can also transmit packets passed to it from that same userspace program.

When QEMU runs your Yocto image, it emulates a virtual hardware device. To emulate the network hardware on this virtual device, QEMU needs a way to get network packets from the real network (on your PC) into the QEMU software, so that they can be passed into the virtual device.

So, when QEMU starts to run your Yocto image, it creates a TAP interface on your PC which is then used to pipe network packets in and out of the virtual device it's emulating.

Creating TAP interfaces on Linux requires higher privileges, and so Yocto automatically runs QEMU as `sudo`. Otherwise, QEMU would fail with a permissions error.